# How to export csv file columnames if that is an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, export, multiple-columns

i am getting an array with names that should be column names of csv file:

```
while($skillLabel   = $skillLabelQuery->fetch_assoc()){
        $skills[]   = $skillLabel['name'];
    }
$gdSkills = implode(',', $skills);


$title = array('Student Name','Student Email','Hallticket Number',$gdSkills,
'Group Discussion Score',$skillsPi,'Personal Interview Score','Result');
```

screen shot of my output is this:
[image]

Actual result what i am looking for is it should be a separate columns like    **Example:** `D-php... E-html... F-ajax...`

how can i do that..?

Comment: Yeah, this line is the culprit `$gdSkills = implode(',', $skills);`

Comment: Sorry i am not getting you @Hackerman i am trying to create new coulumns but it is coming in one column now how can i do that..?

Comment: Could you explain, why you are not able to use the csv-related php-functions? E.g. http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Let me explain it in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the `implode` function....according to the docs:

> **implode** — Join array elements with a string

That's why you are getting your skills together, because of this line:

```
$gdSkills = implode(',', $skills); //This creates an string!!
```

So, in order to get the right result, we need a little bit of refactoring(using `array_merge`):

```
//You don't need implode, your skills array should works just fine
$skills = array('Php Programming Skills','HTML 5','Java'); 

$title = array_merge(array('Student Name','Student Email','Hallticket Number'),$skills,array('Group Discussion Score','Personal Interview Score','Result'));

var_dump($title);
```